# hibernate produces incorrect h2 sequence nextvalue query after spring boot upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I've got a spring boot boot 2 service that I'm upgrading to spring boot 3.
In my tests I use an in memory h2 database.
After the upgrade the tests are failing because h2 doesn't accept the query to get the next value of a sequence.

The query it generates looks like.

```
select <sequence_name>.nextval
```

After some lengthy debugging I figured out that this is because spring/hibernate instantiates the H2Dialect using the default constructor, which sets the version of H2 to 0.0.

This causes hibernate to generate queries targeted for H2 v1.

There are 2 more constructors in the H2Dialect class that try to determine the version of the database used, but they're not being called. This is because they're not set in the `JbdcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService` method in the first place.

In the previous version of hibernate (which spring 2.7 was using) this code was all different, and the correct version of the H2Dialect was set, but in spring 3 this seems broken.

I've already figured out I can kinda work around it bu adding `;MODE=LEGACY` to the h2 url, but I'd rather not set this mode at all.

Is there anything I'm missing here, or is this just broken in spring 3 setups?